# What are the various means to add hidden meaning in a screenplay?

Tags: screenwriting

What are the various means to add hidden meaning in a screenplay? People use anagrams, visual symbolism, allegories, but I am wondering if there are different ways to use anagrams, visual symbolism, allegories and other techniques.

Comment: Film vernacular calls this **subtext**.

Comment: Reading between the lines is the same for movies as it is for any other storytelling medium. Screenplays do have their own specialized format and an expectation that everything is communicated explicitly to the production crew... But even then, you can trust that everyone working on the movie can interpret a story. You don't have to explicitly point out your movie's themes or symbolism if they're well-written enough to stand out.